# How to return a specific element of an array in a document?

Tags: mongodb

I have a table containing documents set up as follows:

```
  _id: 1,
  name: { first: 'John', last: 'Doe' },
  tools: [ 'Tool1', 'Tool2', 'Tool3' ],
  skills: [
            { type: 'carpentry',
              years: 3 },
            { type: 'plumbing',
              year: 5 },
            { type: 'electrical',
              year: 8 }
          ]
}
```

I need to write a script that can search each document in the table and return the value of a specific skill, for example: Find the number of years John Doe has in plumbing.

Since I don't need the full document, `db.table.find({skills: {$elemMatch: {type:'plumbing'}}})` feels unnecessary and would still require me to search the document to find the value I'm looking for. Is there a way to just return the part of the document I'm looking for?

The desired output would be `{type: 'plumbing', year: 5}` so that I could then manipulate that data into another field in the document.

Comment: Please mention your expected output

Comment: You can use aggregate and $projects to show what documents fields need to be visible eg. ````$project````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$skills"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "skills.type": "plumbing"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      skills: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FQPZXPQZKkv)

OR try this if you only want year.

[Mongo Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZEatoBlFnDU)

Comment: This is really useful, but returns an array of the field for all documents. Is there way to make it return the field of only a single specific document?

Comment: Check this https://mongoplayground.net/p/pRQ9AzGuxej

Comment: That looks perfect, now I just have to adjust it for my code. Thanks!